# Docker images layers built on different platforms consider different

Tags: docker

I've noticed that the same docker images built on different platforms (OS where docker engine running) are different. For example, I used to build a heavy docker image on travis CI (ubuntu), then pull it to my local machine (macos) and when I build the image (no modifications) on my mac, it just re-used image layers from the downloaded image. It's no longer the case now, now it builds another image from the scratch. I've looked it up under `docker images` and saw that it switched the tag between two images built on ubuntu and macos.

Did they change it? Are docker images built on different platforms no longer compatible?

P.S. Using the same docker version (docker-ce 17.06.2)

Comment: travis CI has cached docker images, so they may be a bit behind. The ubuntu:latest image changed just recently

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm not talking about OS in the image, I'm talking about the platform docker engine runs on

Comment: ah I misread. not sure what's going on. it *should not* do that :P

Comment: Sometimes it could be because of the file times I guess. You can try using `docker build --cache-from <your published image>` and see if that helps

Comment: Can you provide more details of the build process and how you are ensuring your local environment is the same as travis? Both builds run on linux in the end, and a content hash is a content hash so they should match. It could be something like permissions not being mapped into the Linux VM properly.

Comment: @Matt I just install docker-ce and run docker build, the only difference is the host OS where docker engine is running

Comment: @TarunLalwani tried to use `--cache-from repo/image:tag`, didn't work